# Java UTF-16 Encoding code

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, utf-16, utf

The function that encodes a Unicode Code Point (Integer) to a char array (Bytes) in java is basically this:

```
return new char[] { (char) codePoint };
```

Which is just a cast from the integer value to a char.

I would like to know how this cast is actually done, the code behind that cast to make the conversion from an integer value to a character encoded in UTF-16. I tried looking for it on the java source codes but with no luck.

Comment: In Java, a `char`is not a "byte"-sized (8 bit) entity, but a two-byte value.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure which function you're talking about.

Casting valid `int` code points to `char` will work for code points in the basic multilingual plane just due to how UTF-16 was defined. To convert anything above U+FFFF you should use [Character.toChars(int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars%28int%29) to convert to UTF-16 code units. The algorithm is defined in [RFC 2781](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2781#section-2.1).

Comment: Because of surrogate pairs, not all values of `char` represent valid code-points (outside of a pair) -- even if all values of `char` are valid numbers. E.g. it's not just "anything above 0xffff". +1 For inclusion of the conversion method (which answers the question) and link, however.

Comment: @pst - in case it is not apparent, "anything" in this case means a valid Unicode code point as defined in the spec (Unicode 4 for Java 6).

Comment: @pst - from Unicode 4, [chapter 2](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode4.0.0/ch02.pdf): _the lowest plane, the Basic Multilingual Plane, consists of the range 0000..FFFF._ (numbers are base 16)

Comment: All numbers representable by `char` are valid code points, but not all are valid scalar values. (Scalar values are code points which are not surrogate code points.) So it is true that not all `char` values are scalar values, and not all possible `char` sequences are UTF-16 strings. `Character.toChars`, however, does not check whether the argument is a valid scalar value.

Comment: @pst - ah, I see what you meant in your deleted comment - you were quoting the algorithm: _If U < 0x10000, encode U as a 16-bit unsigned integer and terminate._ I will amend the answer.

Comment: @McDowell It makes sense now -- the thing I was forgetting was some code-points ("surrogates area") are reserved for the purpose of encoding the surrogate pairs (and thus not valid as code-points otherwise). Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0):

The code point is just a number that maps to a character, there's no real conversion going on.  Unicode code points are specified in hexadecimal, so whatever you codePoint is in hex will map to that character (or glyph).

Comment: (Or map to a surrogate pair of `char` ...)

Answer (score 0):

Since a `char` is defined to hold UTF-16 data in Java, this is all there is to it. **Only** if the input is an `int` (i.e. it can represent a Unicode codepoint of U+10000 or greater) is some calculation necessary. All `char` values are already UTF-16.

Comment: Not necessarily true. A `char` is just a 16-bit value (no notion of surrogate pairs by itself). Good for pointing out the range of Unicode vs. `char`, though.

Answer (score 0):

All `char`s in Java are represented internally in UTF-16. This is just mapping the integer value to that `char`.

Comment: Not necessarily true. A `char` is just a 16-bit value (no notion of surrogate pairs by itself). Perhaps should talk about character literals in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Also, char arrays are already UTF-16, in the Java platform.

Comment: Not necessarily true. Even though a `char` is 16 bits, an array of characters can hold data which is not valid UTF-16 (invalid surrogate pairs, for instance). Not all code-points fit in a `char`.

Comment: Right, I meant each char of an array of chars is UTF-16, because of skiforfun's array, however I might have not correctly understood his question.